# Resolving Images for Input Buttons with SDL Tridion Compound Templates

Tags: tridion

I have the following sample code output from a Dreamweaver Template Building Block (DWT TBB) in SDL Tridion 2011:

```
<input type="image" src="tcm:33-1995" name="submit"/>
<img src="tcm:33-1995"/>
```

After the DWT TBB, we are using the Default Finish Actions in the Compound Component Template to resolve the paths etc. When I view this in Template Builder we see that the IMG tag is resolved SRC attribute, but the INPUT tag is ignored.

Is there a way to make the default TBBs resolve INPUT tags as well as IMG tags?

Comment: What version is this Chris?
I just tested your exact syntax here on 2011 SP1 HR1 (replacing the tcm ID of course) and it worked fine using nothing but the DWT, Publish Binaries in Package and Link Resolver TBBs.
After the DWT has run I see that the tridion:href, tridion:type and tridion:targetattribute attributes have been added. Are you getting that?

Comment: Sorry David, I only now see that you already commented with the same answer I just gave. I wish I could upvote your comment more than once, since you also broke it down to the specific TBBs, instead of just saying "Default Finish Actions". :-

Comment: @David - thanks for your post - see my comment on Franks answer

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, that's ok. What's a little rep between friends? Just be sure to vote up more of my answers in future! :) In truth, I wasn't 100% certain that I hadn't missed something obvious, and your answer is more detailed than my quick comment. The end result is the same... Chris's issue is solved. That's the important thing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I put the following in a DWT:

```html
<input type="image" src="tcm:1-90" name="submit"/>
<img src="tcm:1-90" />
```

And then put that DWT in a Page Template like this:

1. DWT
2. Publish Binaries in Package
3. Resolve Links

I end up with this Output item in the end:

```html
<input src="http://localhost/Preview/.../img.jpg"  type="image" name="submit"/>
<img src="http://localhost/Preview/.../img.jpg"  />
```

So how is your output different?

### More info

After the DWT is executed, this is the Output item:

```html
<input type="image" src="tcm:1-90" tridion:href="tcm:1-90" 
       tridion:type="Multimedia" tridion:targetattribute="src" name="submit"/>
<img src="tcm:1-90" tridion:href="tcm:1-90" tridion:type="Multimedia" 
     tridion:targetattribute="src" />
```

The Publish Binaries in Package TBB doesn't modify the Output item, so the Link Resolver changes this to the final Output I showed above.

Comment: OK, this makes some sense - the HTML syntax is actually coming from a Component Field (don't ask why), and not being added by the DWT,  so the actual output is what I said in the post, not what you are seing in your test - I guess I need to add the tridion:type and tridion:targetattribute attributes to my component content and it might work.

Comment: Wow... in that case it's a good thing that I added the "More info" section. I was wondering if that would be useful to anyone. Clearly it was. :-)

Comment: Will the same pair (tridion:type && tridion:targetattribute) apply in case of more arcane reference: <div style="background-image: url(tcm:1-90)!important;"> ?

Comment: [Answering myself] Evidently NO, LinkResolverTemplate is not capable of properly resolving inline CSS resources. BUT, resorting to <style/> block works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you have to use below syntax to resolve the image url in input tag

```
<input type="image" src= "url(tcm:33-1995)" name="submit"/>
```

I hope it may works.